# Taking over an unused HTTP method of a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I have a restful Rails 4.2.1 controller with routes like so:

```
resources :users do
  resources :labels, only: %w(index show update destroy)
end
```

Because this controller's model is incredibly tiny (just a name, an ID, and a couple associations that you wouldn't edit with this controller), I'd like to support mass-editing by `PUT`ting or `PATCH`ing the `/users/:user_id/labels` route. (`PUT` and `PATCH` are unused on the collection, and capture the semantic I'm trying to implement—that is, editing the whole collection.)

The problem is, I don't see how I can do that. I can say something like:

```
resources :users do
  resources :labels, only: %w(index show update destroy) do
    collection do
      patch 'all', to: 'labels#update_many'
    end
  end
end
```

But that would result in a route of `/users/:user_id/labels/all`. Leaving the name string empty or nil seems to silently fail (`rake routes` doesn't show any indication of the route), and omitting it entirely causes an error. Meanwhile, doing something like this:

```
resources :users do
  resources :labels, only: %w(index show update destroy)
  member do
    patch 'labels', to: 'labels#update_many'
  end
end
```

Results in a route of `/users/:id/labels`, which is almost right except that the user ID comes in as `:id` instead of `:user_id`, which makes it difficult to handle fetching the user object.

I suppose I could hardcode the entire route in a root-level `match` command, but that just feels wrong.

Is there some trick I'm not aware of for doing this?

Comment: not sure if it works: patch '/', to: 'labels#update_many'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
resources :users do
  resources :labels, only: %w(index show update destroy)
  patch 'labels', to: 'labels#update_many'
end
```

The result route is:

```
PATCH      /users/:user_id/labels(.:format)          labels#update_many
```

Comment: Nice and clean. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

This little trick also works:

```
resources :labels, only: %w(index update destroy) do
  root to: 'labels#update_many', via: [:patch, :put], as: ''
end
```

When you do this, it wants to generate a redundant `user_labels_root_path` helper; the `as: ''` suppresses that.

However, Dabrorius's answer above is cleaner, so I'm going to use that one instead (modified to match both `PATCH` and `PUT`).